# Magento get CMS page parent

Tags: magento

Is there a way to get the hierarchy parent of the CMS page in Magento - or - getCollection of children CMS pages of the particular page?

This task appears to be simple, but in the dump of the properties and methods of magento cms page object, there is no thing like parent or something like that.

Comment: I remember having the same issue, I think you need to have a look to the model 'enterprise_cms/hierarchy_node'

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the `Enterprise_Cms_Model_Hierarchy_Node` object you can see it contains a `parent_node_id`.

(Also, see DB table `enterprise_cms_hierarchy_node`)

To get the node object from a CMS page ID you could do the following:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('enterprise_cms/hierarchy_node')->getCollection()
$collection->addFieldToFilter('page_id', array('eq' => $yourCmsPageId));
$collection->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Yes, this is a proper way. The description of relatively complicated way of achieving simple thing is that the nodes and hierarchy is subsequently added feature in Magento. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, actually the correct idea that there is. However, relatively complex way that an equally simple hierarchical status accumulates and hierarchy of nodes, and then a description of the new features added possibly ever, ever present in Magento. Thanks for the many times